# Get a named parameter value from request

Tags: craft3, params

Yii's [named parameters](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing#named-parameters) are available in the template. For example, for the following route configuration:

```
'post/<post_id:\d+>' => ['template' => 'post-entry'],
```

The value of `post_id` in my template for the request `post/3` will be `3`.

But **how can I access it from PHP**, for example from the `Craft::app -> getRequest()` ?

**Note:** I don't mean queryString parameters. QueryString parameters can be accessed using `getParam('paramName')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to explicitly grab them from PHP, this should also work:

```
$result = Craft::$app->getRequest()->resolve();
```

From there, you could grab `$result[1]`, which should be an array:

```
array(
    'variables' => array(
        'post_id' => 3,
    ,
    'template' => 'post-entry',
    'p' => 'post/3',
)
```

Comment: For the `routes.php` configuration: `'post/<post_id:\d+>' => [ 'template' => 'post-entry']`, the value of $params is `array( "template"=> "post-entry)"` No clue of post_id but it's available in the template when I do `{{ post_id }}` Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: It's also not available in the template if I do `{{ dump(craft.app.urlManager.routeParams()) }}`, this displays: `array(1) { ["template"]=> string(9) "post-entry" } `. But `{{ post_id }}` => `3` So **a)** I am missing an extra configuration or **b)** it's not there...

Comment: Updated answer... should be more reliable and take into account your route.

Answer (score 4):

It is passed as a parameter to your function

```
public function actionView($post_id){
    Craft::dd($post_id);
}
```

Note: your parameter **must** have the **same** name like defined in your route. You can't access it with `public function actionView($postId)`